# How to restrict the route access to certain limit(say 3) for non-sign up user

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I've routes that offer some features to the users. I want new users to access the routes say for 3 times after that they should be routed back to login page.

We can do it in many ways but which one would be the most robust approach?

For e.g we can save the user session in cookies but if user clear the cookies they can access the routes and that is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Storing cookies on the client devices is not a safe solution. Users can delete their cookies. But it can be useful if you combine this with other methods.

You probably don't have a 100% solution as users can change every information you collect from them for unification. But you can make it as hard as possible.

Let's talk about device unification solutions.

1. **IP**: You can get the user IP, store it on your backend. And link it with user type to detect if the user has access to content or not. There are some downsides of this solution; you need to implement a system to update user access. This means another complexity at the backend; most of your users have dynamic IP addresses. They can change it, and this will cost them 10 minutes.
2. **Cookie**: As you said, they can delete them easily.
3. **Fingerprinting**: There are some unique ways to detect devices. [This](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs) library is one of them. It abuses some browser features to create unique ids. It is a clientside library, and you can create an id and send it to your backend for persisting. The downside of this solution: It blocks the browser for a second or something like that. But even incognito, it creates the same id.

My way: I would combine all of them and use storage with TTL at the backend. My document would be like this:

- Random generated device id at cookie: string
- Fingerprint: string
- IP: string
- User features: bit flag value
- Visit number for the feature: int

Whenever a user deletes or changes cookies, I would identify the user from IP or fingerprint. Whenever a user changed its IP, I will identify it from other unique ids I have. And also, on each change, I would update this document. When the user bought new features, I would update the bit flag value. Also, if I can't link this visit with any of the previous visits already existing in the database, I would create a new document.